# How to merge two DataStreams in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using Flink to process my streaming data.

I have two data sources: A and B.

```
// A
DataStream<String> dataA = env.addSource(sourceA);
// B
DataStream<String> dataB = env.addSource(sourceB);
```

I use `map` to process the data coming from A and B.

```
DataStream<String> res = mergeDataAAndDataB();   // how to merge dataA and dataB?
```

Saying that sourceA is sending: `"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"...`, sourceB is sending: `"A", "B", "C"...`.

What I'm trying to do is to merge them as `Aaaa, Bbbb, Cccc...` to generate a new `DataStream<String>` object.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two kinds of stream merging in Flink.

```
dataA.union(dataB)
```

will create one new stream that has the elements of both streams, blended in some arbitrary way, perhaps `"aaa", "bbb", "A", "ccc", "B", "C"`, which isn't what you've asked for -- just mentioning it for completeness.

What you do want is to create a connected stream, via

```
dataA.connect(dataB)
```

which you can then process with a `RichCoFlatMapFunction` or a `KeyedCoProcessFunction` to compute a sort of join that glues the strings together.

You'll find a [tutorial on the topic of connected streams](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/etl.html#connected-streams) in the Flink documentation, and an example that's reasonably close in the [training exercises that accompany the tutorials](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/tree/master/rides-and-fares).

Comment: I wonder, if there is an API that preserves ordering during merge/union. As an example streams [1,2,3,5] and [2,4,6] will be merged as [1,2,2,3,4,5,6]